# Troubleshooting: Several plugins deactivate at random times

Tags: troubleshooting

For some reason several (but not all) plugins on my [live site](https://attac.no/) deactivate themselves at times. Some of them are my own plugins (mostly stuff that could have been in functions.php, but I prefer dedicated plugins), others are from the repository.

It seems to be all plugins added recently (I switched themes and updated the site recently).

I have no idea what is causing it, but the result is that some things on the live site doesn't display properly.

I added debugging to a log file, but there's nothing in it that can explain what happens. There are some PHP errors that I'm not sure where are coming from (`PHP Notice:  Function is_post_type_archive was called incorrectly.` and `PHP Notice:  Function is_tax was called incorrectly.`), but they don't seem to have do anything to do with the deactivation.

How can I figure out what's causing this, and fix it?

Comment: the only thing in WP itself that would do this is if you activated a plugin and it generated a fatal error, the plugin activation page would deactivate it and show a prompt, but this would require the plugin to be deactivated first, and for you to click on the activate button and see the error, so this is not the cause of your issue unless you have a rogue admin going in and changing things. It sounds like an audit log plugin might be needed.

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell. Can you recommended an audit log plugin?

Comment: no, but given you switched themes recently, it's possible the theme has code to disable plugins, the only way to know if this is the case is by reading the code or finding other people who use that theme/plugins who experience the same thing. It's rare but it has been known to happen when theme vendors are not very reputable

Comment: I'm using Twenty Twenty Three, so I doubt that the theme is to blame. My guess it is something that resets some setting somewhere, as the plugins that are disabled all where installed recently. It might be a plugin that causes this of course, but as long as I can't figure out exactly what happens, it difficult to find the cause.

Comment: I see, there isn't enough information here to identify the cause though, it sounds like you don't have enough technical information to debug this, or identify what's happening. That needs to be done before you can write this question in a way that's answerable

Comment: What I'm looking for is some way to find out what's going on. I have no clue and don't know where to look. What kind of technical information would help?

Comment: you basically need to catch it in the act and be able to log when it happens, right now you don't have the tools to do that. There is no golden path or canonical approach to solving this other than audit logs, disabling things, and checking for security plugins/code protections that might be resetting the plugin list. I know that's not helpful but it's the best you'd get until you gain more clues. Note that I'm not allowed to recommend a plugin here, nor are you allowed to ask as that's offtopic here